# Created String objects count

Tags: java, string

I am reading certification book and here I have faced with confusing problem. The book says that this line of code creates only one String object, but I think 2 objects are created. Am I right?

```
String summer = new String("Summer");
```

Doesn't the constant literal "Summer" created and placed in String constant Pool?

EDIT: Guys I'm getting confused I need exact answer. Here are different posts says both 1 object & 2 object is creating.

Comment: Yes, but as it's a string constant pool, the `new String()` will not create it again, because it's already there. The same reference will be used.

Comment: @TillHelge I think it will not use the same reference because ("Summer" == new String("Summer")) will always return false. Or I have misunderstood your post?

Comment: @ArsenAlexanyan to compare strings: `"Summer".equals(new String("Summer"))`;

Comment: Yes I know but question is how many String objects are created.

Comment: one object, an one reference after the line of code summer

Comment: String summer - reference. "Summer" - constant internend. New String of a constant to same reference re used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *creation* might be the cause of your confusion. In fact, you are right: Two string instances are involved in the line

```
String summer = new String("Summer");
```

As there are two string instances involved, they must have been created somwhere and sometime.

The creation time is the big difference. The `"Summer"` is a constant which is loaded into the internal string pool when loading the class that contains this constant. So this *internal* string instance is created while loading the class.

The string object that the variable `summer` refers to is created while running the code that contains this line. That's it.

Comment: Wow interesting answer I will choose this after some suggestions. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

```
String summer = new String("Summer");
```

This will create only one instance of String. And it will not be in the String pool until you call `intern()` on it.

Comment: The instance is the new String(...). But how about "Summer" constant? Doesn't it created?

Comment: No it's not. And I hope by constant you are referring to String literal.

Comment: Yes I am reffering to String literal. Thanks!